# Metal address space specifier 'device'

Tags: ios, shader, metal

In Metal Shading language, what is the significance of keyword 'device' before a type? Example:

```
device float4 *buffer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to objects from the device's memory that you can both read and write.

[From Metal Shading Language Specification:](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)

> The `device` address space name refers to buffer memory objects allocated from the device memory pool **that are both readable and writeable**.

Answer (score 1):

Metal requires you to use **device** or some other address space attribute whenever you pass a pointer into a shader function.

[From Metal Shading Language Specification Version 2.0:](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)

> Arguments to Metal graphics and kernel functions declared in a program that are pointers must be declared with the Metal device, threadgroup, threadgroup_imageblock, or constant address space attribute.

The type of the function (vertex, fragment, kernel) limits the available address spaces.

For graphics functions, use the **device** address space for read/write buffers, or the **constant** address space for read-only buffers. Textures are assumed to be in **device** space.

Comment: I don't think "use the device address space for read/write buffers, or the constant address space for read-only buffers" is true.  There is always `const device` for read-only buffers. The`constant` address space has different alignment requirements to `device` address space (256-byte vs 16-byte) and I have a feeling it's contents get copied into a L2 cache or somesuch, however don't have a definitive answer on this.